# Bootstrap 3.1 documentation - Download examples

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, documentation

I'm totally new to Bootstrap. After some initial success I came across a very silly problem.

On the website of getbootstrap.com there are some examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

But I can not find the way to download them. Can you please help me?

I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can from the github, go to this link "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap" download the zip file, the examples files in "bootstrap-master\docs\examples\carousel".

Comment: Thank you! As soon as I have 15 reputation I'll update your answer!

Comment: @tsGucci If this solved your problem, you can accept it regardless of reputation

Answer (score 1):

open up the sample by clicking on it
after the sample is displayed in your browser, right click the page and select "view source"
copy the source
paste it into another file
save

Comment: Thank you! This is a great help!

Comment: if this worked for you, can you mark the answer as correct/useful?

Comment: Sorry I do not have enough reputation to do so. Especially because somebody minused my question...

Answer (score 0):

You can download it all, go the the website and search for : `downloading the bootstrap repo`

[image]